# Access to Azure Devops working elements via C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, tfs, devops

Is it possible to build a C# application that I can use to access my Azure Devops server and have my work items read out for a particular sprint? If so how, I can't find anything that works. Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 2):

Azure DevOps ships with a standard REST API for most parts and a slightly more archaic SOAP API for most of the rest.

There is documentation available here:

- [.NET Client Library for REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops)
- [.NET Client library for SOAP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/soapsamples?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops)
- [Pure REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

For more specific problems, post a new question.

To get work items by iteration, you'd be looking at this API:

- [Iterations - Get Iteration Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/get-iteration-work-items?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)
- .NET Client Library for REST API: [WorkHttpClientBase.GetIterationWorkItemsAsync(TeamContext, Guid, Object, CancellationToken) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.work.webapi.workhttpclientbase.getiterationworkitemsasync?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops-dotnet#Microsoft_TeamFoundation_Work_WebApi_WorkHttpClientBase_GetIterationWorkItemsAsync_Microsoft_TeamFoundation_Core_WebApi_Types_TeamContext_System_Guid_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

You can find the nugets here:

- [.NET Client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops)

A sample using the WorkTrackingClient (not the exact API) is here:

- [microsoft
  /
  azure-devops-dotnet-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/WorkItemTracking/QueriesSample.cs)